# Getting the USB hub port of an open handle

Tags: windows, usb, port

I have a situation where my product enumerates to Windows and I can see it and all its sub components.

My problem is that there is a:

```
USB Connector - HUB - Port 1 - USB Component
                      Port 2 - USB Component
                      Port 3 - USB Component
                      Port 4 - USB Component
```

At the time of enumeration the USB Components all the look the same.  They have a serial number that is programmed into them at manufacture time, but it is not marked on the part.  I can open the device by the serial number.  What I need to do after I open it, is to find out what hub port the device is on so that I can be sure I opened the proper part.  If I have the wrong one I can open the next until I get the proper port.  How can I tell which port the open handler is on?  I can try IOCTL or SetupDi but I do not know what to look at or what to do with the data when it comes back.

Basically I have an open pipe/handle to a device on a hub, I want to find out what hub port that handle is pointing to.

Any ideas?

Comment: If you can identify and open the devices by serial number, why do you care about figuring out what USB port they are plugged into?

Comment: You should try compiling and running [usbview](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/usb/usbview) from Microsoft to see if it has the information you need.  If it does, you can inspect its source code to see how it gets that information using Windows APIs.